# Перестали подтягиваться бины ВООБЩЕ после перехода с JDBC на DATA JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

учусь работать с базой данных и Spring Security. стек - Springboot, spring dataJPA, postgeSQL
сначала попробовал с JDBC, потом решил переделать на DATA JPA, после переходы перестал запускаться Spring, вот что пишет(все прикреплять не буду, там про каждый бин):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [D:\project\SpringMVCApp1\target\classes\ru\popov\springcourse\config\SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDetailsService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtPersonDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPersonDAO' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAO' defined in file [D:\project\SpringMVCApp1\target\classes\ru\popov\springcourse\dao\PersonDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in ru.popov.springcourse.repository.PersonRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract ru.popov.springcourse.models.Person ru.popov.springcourse.repository.PersonRepository.findByPersonName(java.lang.String)! No property personName found for type Person!
```

Все классы расположены в нужных папках, я эти варианты уже проверил. пробовал опускаться до версии ниже.
по предложенyому логом дебагу вылетает следующий Exception:

```
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2932e15f': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createSharedEntityManager' parameter 1: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [java.util.Map] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
```

вот мой POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>ru.popov.springcourse</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-app1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>SpringMVCApp1</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>    
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
          <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

вот мой model Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name should not empty!")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Name should be between 2 and 30 characters")
    private String name;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "Age should be greater than 0")
    private int age;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Email should be empty!")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Password should be between 2 char")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
```

Вот мой Репо:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    Person findByPersonName(String name);
}
```

Вот мой Service:

```
@Service
public class PersonDAO {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDAO(PersonRepository personRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }


    public Person register(Person person) {
       Role roleUser = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
       List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<>();
       userRoles.add(roleUser);
       person.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(person.getPassword()));
       person.setRoles(userRoles);
        return personRepository.save(person);

    }

    public List<Person> index() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Person findByPersonName(String personName) {

        return personRepository.findByPersonName(personName);
    }

    public Person show(int id) {

        return personRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Person person) {
        personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void update(int id, Person person) {
        Person updatePerson = show(id);
        updatePerson.setName(person.getName());
        updatePerson.setAge(person.getAge());
        updatePerson.setPassword(person.getPassword());
        updatePerson.setEmail(person.getEmail());
        personRepository.save(updatePerson);
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        personRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract ru.popov.springcourse.models.Person ru.popov.springcourse.repository.PersonRepository.findByPersonName(java.lang.String)! No property personName found for type Person!

Здесь он пишет, что не может найти параметр personName для Person.
Хотелось бы посмотреть твои модели и репозитории.
Если есть возможность, прикрепи.

Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in ru.popov.springcourse.repository.PersonRepository

Тут он пишет о проблемах с репозиторием. Аннотации везде стоят, везде есть имплементация JpaRepository?

Comment: дополнил тело овпроса

Comment: я сам допетрил.. findByPersonName - findByName. Благодарю за подсказку